# OAuth-авторизация — "invalid_client","error_description":"client_id is incorrect" (VK API)

Tags: vkontakte-api, laravel, вконтакте, oauth

Проект на Laravel 5.2.

Файл **/config/services.php**

```
'vkontakte' => [
'client_id' => '*****',
'client_secret' => '***********',
'redirect' => 'http://*****.loc/auth/vkontakte/callback/'
]
```

При отправке запроса (метод обработчик)

```
public function redirectToProvider($socialNetworkName)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($socialNetworkName)->redirect();
    })
```

приходит ответ

> {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"client_id is
>   incorrect"}

С VK API работаю впервые... подскажите, в какую сторону хоть смотреть?

Comment: Убедись, что с client_id все в порядке. Это ID приложения из вк, которое ты завел. У новых созданных приложений это 7 цифр помоему.

Comment: Да 7 цифр вставлял копипастом - ошибки точно нет!